# removing vbseo (VB4) and redirect indexed URLs to new ones by .htsccess rule

Tags: vbulletin

Actually I think VBSEO just causes pressure on server and i don't need it anymore, So i want to disable it on VB 4.2

The most important thing is topic URLs that will change and i will lose my google traffic. I need a rule to redirect old URLs to new default vbulletin URLs.

Now I'm using these rewrite settings :

Forum URL : 004 - Non-hierarchic .html type URLs using IDs (used at www.DaniWeb.com)
Member Profle URL : 005 - Non-hierarchic directory type URLs using IDs (used at www.MustangEvolution.com)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20130122142454/http://www.vbseo.com/blogs/mert-goekceimam/how-uninstall-vbseo-238/) at vBSEO.com for .htaccess rewrite rules to redirect back to old `showthread.php?t=1233` urls.

Comment: The VBSEO web site is down. For reference, the same info on how to deinstall VBSEO is replicated here: [http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?p=302867909](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?p=302867909)

Answer (score 0):

If You have your thread rewrite rules set as **forum-name/threadid-threadname.html** use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/([0-9]+)-[^/]+\.html /forums/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have your thread rewrite rules set as **forum-name/threadid-threadname/** use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/([0-9]+)-[^/]+ /forums/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have your thread rewrite rules set as **forum-name/threadname-threadid.html** use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/[^/]+-([0-9]+)\.html /forums/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have your thread rewrite rules set as **forum-name/threadname-threadid/** use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/[^/]+-([0-9]+)/ /forums/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

----> If your forum is not domain.tld/forums, remove "/forums" part. <----